# Shape Context for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm totally new in Python and I want to use the "shape context"-algorithm in Python. I saw on [github](https://github.com/creotiv/Python-Shape-Context) that someone already made the effort to program this, but I think his program code was used with OpenCV 2 and it is not compatible with OpenCV 3.
Because of the missing experience I don't know how to fix his code to work on OpenCV 3.
I want to take this algorithm in Python because my previous programming is also in Python.

Please help me and don't be to rude if I made mistakes.

Comment: i think you should uninstall opencv3 and install 2

Comment: and how is it possible to install opencv2 on a mac? I tried installing over pip and easy_install...

Comment: on this page it is described how to instal OpenCV3 and not 2 or am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks, but brew install OpenCV3

Comment: the idea is brew install opencv 2

Comment: brew install opencv@2 is the solution. Thanks everybody! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try using 2to3 library.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html.
If it still doesn't work, You are left with either changing not working parts Yourself(asking someone who will do it for You) or using 2.7 interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, but the code should transformed from OpenCV2 to OpenCV3.

Comment: So you want to use code which was written in python 2.7, which using library written in python 2.7 in Python 3.X using library written in 3.X. Unless you don't do some work yourself i don't think it will work. Would say your best bet is just to use python 2.7 and opencv2 for this project.

Comment: Ok, but how is it possible to install OpenCV2 on a Mac? Nothing worked for me

Comment: For sure is, I neither have Mac or use OpenCV2, so won't help you much here, but here is first link i found googling it: https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/.